# Excel - Run time error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a procedure that is checking if an excel sheet has the correct number of columns.
The excel workbooks being passed into my procedure all have a various number of tabs. My code originally only checked the first tab in the workbook for the number of columns (and this wasn't always the sheet that required checking).

This was done by setting the workbook using the following code which always took the first sheet in excel:

```
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
```

I have now updated my code to pass a SheetName into the procedure to be used. However sometimes the value of this variable (wbSheetName) is blank due to there only being 1 tab in excel (and the tab names differ month on month so it's easier to leave this blank).

So due to this I have included an IF statement staying if this is blank to set my wbSheetName to 1, in order to cater for it being the first sheet.

I then updated my code to the following:

```
Set ws = wb.Sheets(wbSheetName)
```

The above code works fine when a value is assigned to the wbSheetName variable. For example if the tab is assigned June Report it works and goes to that tab and gets the columns etc.

However for the cases where wbSheetName is set to 1 I get an error:

```
Run time error 9 subscript out of range
```

I have debugged and can see that the value is 1, so it should be taking the first sheet. I am not sure what the issue is as it works fine when I have it hard coded as 1 but not when wbSheetName is assigned a value of 1.

My code is below:

```
Public Sub SheetCheck(FilePath As String, FileType As String, wbSheetName As String)

        'Edit wbSheetName variable so that it only incudes sheet name and not the range
        If wbSheetName = "" Then
            'Set to first sheet in file
            wbSheetName = 1
        
        ElseIf InStr(wbSheetName, "!") Then
            
            'Other code here that works and assigns wbSheetName a string value such as June Report
        
        Else
            wbSheetName = wbSheetName
        
        End If
        
    
        'Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(wbSheetName)
        
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: `wbSheetName = 1` is equivalent to `wbSheetName = "1"`. You're trying to use a `String` as an index, which you can't do.

Comment: You can also access the first worksheet in a file, I believe, by `Dim ws as Worksheet / Set ws = Activeworkbook.worksheets(1)`.

Comment: Thank you both. I've just added in an additional IF statement in order to get around it.